# Animate backgroundPostion always returns 50%?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do a very very simple mouseover that animates a change in background position.

**js**

```
$('li.services_w')
    .css({
        backgroundPosition: "0px 0px"
    })
    .mouseover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: "(0px -35px)"
        }, {
            duration: 500
        })
    })
    .mouseout(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: "(0px 0px)"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            complete: function () {
                $(this).css({
                    backgroundPosition: "0px 0px"
                })
            }
        })
    });
```

Except everytime I run this code, the background always returns `background-position: 0 50%` as the outcome of the mouseover. No matter what I change those numbers too! I assure you this is the only javascript I am using.

**css**

```
.services_w {
  height: 35px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: url("../img/services_w.jpg") repeat 0px 0px;
}
.services_w:hover {
  background-position: 0px -35px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="grid_10 nav">
  <ul class="lavaLamp">
    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li class="services_w"><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
    ...
```

Comment: Try removing the `()` around it.

Comment: I think Nick got it ==> http://jsfiddle.net/nr75d/ -------------- Finally, save a few key strokes with `.hover()` ==> http://jsfiddle.net/Sqv6Q/

Comment: @nick craver, what () are you talking about?

Comment: @Trip - For example: "(0px 0px)", try just "0px 0px"...I'm not sure what effect the `()` has in different browsers.

Comment: Hey you're absolutely right! No idea how that worked for the original blog @ http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/  . But removing them cures the problem. Thanks so much guys,

Comment: @Trip - Added it as an answer to help the nest google, but take a look at `.hover()` like I have above, makes it much cleaner, especially when there are child elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra `"(....)"` that's invalid CSS, like this:

```
$('li.services_w')
    .css( {backgroundPosition: "0px 0px"} )
    .mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"0px -35px"}, {duration:500})
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"0px 0px"}, {duration:200, complete:function(){
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: "0px 0px"})
        }})
    });
```

Or a bit cleaner using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and specifying the duration directly:

```
$('li.services_w').css( {backgroundPosition: "0px 0px"} )
    .hover(function(){
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({backgroundPosition:"0px -35px"}, 500);
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({backgroundPosition:"0px 0px"}, 200);
    });
```

Comment: Out of speculation, that second cleaner version doesn't actually animate it. somehow the animate gets deprecated by the mouseover and its an instant change.

Comment: @Trip - You can adjust the `.stop()` parameters depending on the exact behavior you want, the  first tells it whether to clear the queue, the second tells it whether to finish the first animation, so you may just want `.stop(true)` instead of `.stop(true, true)`.

Comment: I thought of that but it wasn't it. Its quirky because if I animate opacity or any other attribute it works as expected. But background attribute is not animated.

Comment: @Trip - You sure this code isn't running twice or anything? Would love to see the actual page you're having issues on, something out of the ordinary going on.